Using intersection point shapefile to create geocode locator in ArcGIS Pro
I have a shapefile of all intersections within our city. It contains a intersection name (i.e. street 1 / street 2) and the individual streets listed as separate attributes. I have an excel list of intersections, now these can be poorly formatted (i.e. street 1 at street 2, street 3 @ street 4, street 5 & street 6 etc.). However, all the street information is there in the excel table.
I'm using ArcGIS Pro 3.0 and I tried creating a locator using the intersection shapefile, while assigning the role of POI to the intersection geocode locator. However, when I bring in the excel file to geocode, it returns with 0 matches. I know in my list that there are at least a couple that will match based on the text. For example, in my shapefile, there's an intersection at First Ave / Second Ave E. In my excel list, there are several records with the same wording (First Ave / Second Ave E). I'm assuming I set up on geocoder incorrectly, but I don't know what I need to change.

Can you give some details on how you set up the geocoder? Screenshots of tools run and samples of what data looks like (field names, data types, example data, etc.) can be helpful in troubleshooting.
